# Take control on select_related

Tags: django, django-orm

I need to get the latest image of the creator for each event.

For example I have 3 models:

```
class Event(..):
   create_by = ForeignKey(User, related_name='events_set')

class User(..):
...

class ProfileImage(..):
   user = ForeignKey(User, related_name='profile_images_set')
   image = ImageField(..)
```

So i need to get detail info about Event, I have got a guery like this:

```
Event.objects.all().prefetch_related('..').select_related('created_by')
```

The problem is that I also need to get the last image of event creator. 
I tried `Prefetch` but it only works to control `prefetch_related`.
Something like this:

```
Event.objects.all().prefetch_related('..').select_related(Prefetch('created_by', queryset=User.objects.latest('pk').prefetch_related('profile_images_set'))
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What exactly do you want here? The latest image of the creator for each event?

Comment: @DanielRoseman You are right